# Col Span layout rule isn't working as expected

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to the AP Bills and Adjustments screen (AP301000), where I'm trying to get the Description field to span the first two columns in the header (there are three columns).  Unfortunately, it moves fields from the second column over to the first, and offset from the left a little bit. Here is my customization:

[image]

Here is the header before adding the column span layout rule:

[image]

And here  is the header after publication of the customization:

[image]

I've tried many different approaches, but I can't get it to simply span the two columns, while leaving everything else alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my version it is already spanning two columns:
[image]

The layout is broken because the description field overlaps some of the new fields you added in the second column. There needs to be some space available in the second column for description to expand otherwise it will move the fields that overlap in the second column below description like in your screenshot.

To avoid overlap you could add some dummy label controls above description layout rule so it pushes description down below the last field added in second column:
[image]

Add enough dummy labels to make sure description position is below the last field of second column.

[image]

Comment: Adding the dummy labels did the trick - thanks much, Hugues!!